# C# Multiplying two variables of value int.MaxValue does not result in OverflowException

Tags: c#, int

I've got an integer array that contains two values, each the maximum value of int32:

```
int[] factors = new int[] { 2147483647, 2147483647 };
```

I'm *trying* to get the product of these two numbers to create an OverflowException:

```
try
{
    int product = factors[0] * factors [1];
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

Much to my surprise (and dismay), product actually returns a value of 1.  Why is this, and how would I go about throwing an exception when the product of two integers exceeds int.MaxValue?

Comment: Can you make 'product' Int64?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the default behavior of C# is not to check overflow with int.
However, you can force overflow checking by using [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) keyword.

```
try
{
    checked
    {
        int product = factors[0] * factors [1];
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

Comment: This is correct -- note that there is also a "used checked by default" option on the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to call BigMul of the math class(used to multiply large integers and avoid overflow),or else even without exception,by using the * operator will result in 1.

```
long product = Math.BigMul(factors[0], factors[1]);
```

to throw the exception you will have to place checked.

```
checked
{
     int product = factors[0] * factors[1];
}
```

great tutorial about overflow by using the checked and unchecked

> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7776/Arithmetic-Overflow-Checking-using-checked-uncheck

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose it in a `checked` block to throw an overflow exception. Replace `int product = factors[0] * factors [1];` with this:

```
checked
{
    int product = factors[0] * factors [1];
}
```

Without the `checked` block the result will be truncated since it exceeds `int`'s maximum capacity.