# Trying to create a form calculator using C#, unsure of "System.FormatException" error

Tags: c#

```
namespace Calculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Number1.Text);
            int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Number2.Text);
            int result = 0;
            string resultString = Convert.ToString(result);

            if (Addition.Checked == true)
            {
                result = num1 + num2;
                resultBox.Text = resultString;
            }
           else if (Subtraction.Checked == true)
            {
                result = num1 - num2;
                resultBox.Text = resultString;
            }
            else if (Multiplication.Checked == true)
            {
                result = num1 * num2;
                resultBox.Text = resultString;
            }
            else
            {
                resultBox.Text = "Error, no parameter selected";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that most of it is right, it seems to be the converting that is tripping me up. I'm new to C# (first day!) so i'm a bit confused. Also first post on this website, so sorry for any formatting problems.

Comment: Add a breakpoint and debug. You can see where the code generates the error.

Comment: The error is on the Convert.ToInt32 but i'm unsure how to rectify the error. As far as I know I'm converting the string to an int, calculating the sum and then reconverting it back to a string

Comment: try using `try.Parse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32()`

Comment: When you want to parse text to an integer its a good idea to use tryParse. You can find more information about that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: In addition to using `TryParse`, you need to use your `ResultString` AFTER your calculation. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like an issue with trying to convert to a number. Instead of using `Convert.ToInt32()`, try `TryParse()` instead:

```
int num1;
int num2;
bool isNum1Valid = int.TryParse(Number1.Text, out num1);
bool isNum2Valid = int.TryParse(Number2.Text, out num2);

if (!isNum1Valid)
{
    // num1 is invalid. Throw an error message or something
}

if (!isNum2Valid)
{
    // num2 is invalid. Throw an error message or something
}
```

Your other issue in your code is that your converting `ResultString` before you are parsing the result. Use this line AFTER you do your calculation:

```
string resultString = result.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Icemanind`'s solution is very good, but you can consider not allowing the user to enter incorrect number from the beginning (something like a numeric text box). Several solutions are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers?answertab=votes#tab-top):

```
private void FirstNumber_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
}
```

Also, you should consider overflowing (* may easily get past Int32.MaxValue for numbers large enough), as it may lead to unexpected results, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775846/c-sharp-multiplying-two-variables-of-value-int-maxvalue-does-not-result-in-overf):

```
try
{
    checked
    {
        // may be used for all operations

        int product = num1 * num2;
    }
}
catch(OverflowException ex)
{
    resultBox.Text = "Integer operation overflow";
}
```

OR

Declare product as `Int64` to make sure it accommodates all possible results.

Thus, you can be almost certain that you have valid numbers in your text boxes.

Comment: This is good. Only issue is it can still allow for empty values (unless the textbox has a default value of 0 or something)

Comment: Yes, checking for empty is still needed. Also, parsing trials are needed, since user may paste the numbers from somewhere (unless pasting is disabled). So, this should be regarded as a complementary answer to make the interface more friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check for null or empty values before attempting to convert.

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmptry(Number2.Text))
  num2 = 0;
else
  num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Number2.Text);
```

You are also converting 'result' to 'resultString' before you are setting a the answer to 'result.' You should move

```
resultBox.Text = resultString;
```

To below the if-else block.

Answer (score 0):

you should place `string resultString = Convert.ToString(result);` after calculation

```
private void Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int num1 = Number1.Text==""?0:Convert.ToInt32(Number1.Text);
            int num2 = Number2.Text==""?0:Convert.ToInt32(Number2.Text);
            int result = 0;


            if (Addition.Checked == true)
            {
                result = num1 + num2;
            }
           else if (Subtraction.Checked == true)
            {
                result = num1 - num2;
            }
            else if (Multiplication.Checked == true)
            {
                result = num1 * num2;
            }
            else
            {
                resultBox.Text = "Error, no parameter selected";
            }
        string resultString = Convert.ToString(result);
            resultBox.Text = resultString;
        }
```